# PHP Login using CURL not working

Tags: php, curl

I want to login website bukalapak.com, but I have problem I just got blank page after execute this php, here my code :

```
var_dump(login_bukalapak());
function login_bukalapak(){
    $data_login = array(
        'user_session[username]' => 'myusername',
        'user_session[password]' => 'mypassword'
    );
    $url = "https://www.bukalapak.com/user_sessions";
    $ch = curl_init();    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    $cookie = 'cookies.txt';
    $timeout = 30;

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_login);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    /*$url = "https://www.bukalapak.com/products/new?from=dropdown";
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);*/

    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
}
```

I confuse I just have return blank, how the correct answer to make it run well and return successfully login ?
Thanks.

Comment: do they allow automated logins?

Comment: @rlfm yes, they do

Comment: thats not what their terms of service says

Comment: @rtfm really? i can't find any relevant sections in their TOS, i only found a section basically saying "the TOS also applies to the bupalak applications" (probably referring to some smartphone app), which section are you referring to when you say they don't allow it? as far as i can tell from reading the TOS, they don't have any policy on it at all.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing many things wrong here.

1: their login system use application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding for the login POST request body, but your code try to login using multipart/form-data encoding.

2: their login system requires you to have a pre-existing cookie session before logging in, but your code does not obtain a cookie session prior to sending the login request.

3: they use a CSRF token scheme to protect their login, where you need to fetch the csrf token from the page, and add it to your login post fields before sending the login request, called `authenticity_token` (it's in their html as `<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<TOKEN>" />`), your code makes no attempt to fetch and extract this token prior to logging in.

4: there is a bunch of login parameters you're missing, namely `utf8`, `user_session[remember_me]`, `comeback`, `button`, and as i said previously, `authenticity_token`  - not all of these parameters may be required, or perhaps all of them are, but at least some of them (`authenticity_token`) is 100% sure to be required, just add them all, unless you wanna waste time figuring out which parameters are required and which is not, it's probably not worth the effort.

5: your code lacks error checking, curl_setopt returns bool(false) if there was a problem setting your settings, and curl_exec returns bool(false) if there was a problem during the transfer

with that in mind, here is a sample implementation in [hhb_curl](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php) that i *think* would work with a real username/password:

```
<?php
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = login_bukalapak ( "foo@bar.com", "password" );
var_dump ( $hc->exec ( 'https://www.bukalapak.com/' )->getStdOut () );
function login_bukalapak(string $username, string $password): \hhb_curl {
    $hc = new hhb_curl ( '', true );
    $html = $hc->exec ( 'https://www.bukalapak.com/' )->getStdOut ();
    $domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
    $data_login = getDOMDocumentFormInputs ( $domd, true, false ) ['new_user_session'];
    // var_dump ( $data_login ) & die ();
    assert ( isset ( $data_login ['user_session[username]'], $data_login ['user_session[password]'] ), 'username/password field not found in login form!' );
    $data_login ['user_session[username]'] = $username;
    $data_login ['user_session[password]'] = $password;
    $url = "https://www.bukalapak.com/user_sessions";

    $html = $hc->setopt_array ( array (
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.bukalapak.com/user_sessions',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( $data_login ) 
    ) )->exec ()->getStdOut ();
    //var_dump ( $html );
    $domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
    $xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
    $loginErrorEles = $xp->query ( '//*[contains(@class,"__error") and not(contains(@class,"hidden"))]' );
    $loginErrors = '';
    foreach ( $loginErrorEles as $loginError ) {
        if (empty ( $loginError->textContent )) {
            continue;
        }
        $loginErrors .= trim ( $loginError->textContent );
    }
    if (! empty ( $loginErrors )) {
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'failed to log in: '.$loginErrors);
    }
    // assuming logged in successfully
    // note that its highly unreliable, they sometimes say "wrong username/password", and someitmes not, seemingly randomly.
    return $hc;
}
function getDOMDocumentFormInputs(\DOMDocument $domd, bool $getOnlyFirstMatches = false, bool $getElements = true): array {
    // :DOMNodeList?
    if (! $getOnlyFirstMatches && ! $getElements) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException ( '!$getElements is currently only implemented for $getOnlyFirstMatches (cus im lazy and nobody has written the code yet)' );
    }
    $forms = $domd->getElementsByTagName ( 'form' );
    $parsedForms = array ();
    $isDescendantOf = function (\DOMNode $decendant, \DOMNode $ele): bool {
        $parent = $decendant;
        while ( NULL !== ($parent = $parent->parentNode) ) {
            if ($parent === $ele) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    // i can't use array_merge on DOMNodeLists :(
    $merged = function () use (&$domd): array {
        $ret = array ();
        foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
            $ret [] = $input;
        }
        foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "textarea" ) as $textarea ) {
            $ret [] = $textarea;
        }
        foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "button" ) as $button ) {
            $ret [] = $button;
        }
        return $ret;
    };
    $merged = $merged ();
    foreach ( $forms as $form ) {
        $inputs = function () use (&$domd, &$form, &$isDescendantOf, &$merged): array {
            $ret = array ();
            foreach ( $merged as $input ) {
                // hhb_var_dump ( $input->getAttribute ( "name" ), $input->getAttribute ( "id" ) );
                if ($input->hasAttribute ( "disabled" )) {
                    // ignore disabled elements?
                    continue;
                }
                $name = $input->getAttribute ( "name" );
                if ($name === '') {
                    // echo "inputs with no name are ignored when submitted by mainstream browsers (presumably because of specs)... follow suite?", PHP_EOL;
                    continue;
                }
                if (! $isDescendantOf ( $input, $form ) && $form->getAttribute ( "id" ) !== '' && $input->getAttribute ( "form" ) !== $form->getAttribute ( "id" )) {
                    // echo "this input does not belong to this form.", PHP_EOL;
                    continue;
                }
                if (! array_key_exists ( $name, $ret )) {
                    $ret [$name] = array (
                            $input 
                    );
                } else {
                    $ret [$name] [] = $input;
                }
            }
            return $ret;
        };
        $inputs = $inputs (); // sorry about that, Eclipse gets unstable on IIFE syntax.
        $hasName = true;
        $name = $form->getAttribute ( "id" );
        if ($name === '') {
            $name = $form->getAttribute ( "name" );
            if ($name === '') {
                $hasName = false;
            }
        }
        if (! $hasName) {
            $parsedForms [] = array (
                    $inputs 
            );
        } else {
            if (! array_key_exists ( $name, $parsedForms )) {
                $parsedForms [$name] = array (
                        $inputs 
                );
            } else {
                $parsedForms [$name] [] = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    unset ( $form, $tmp, $hasName, $name, $i, $input );
    if ($getOnlyFirstMatches) {
        foreach ( $parsedForms as $key => $val ) {
            $parsedForms [$key] = $val [0];
        }
        unset ( $key, $val );
        foreach ( $parsedForms as $key1 => $val1 ) {
            foreach ( $val1 as $key2 => $val2 ) {
                $parsedForms [$key1] [$key2] = $val2 [0];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($getElements) {
        return $parsedForms;
    }
    $ret = array ();
    foreach ( $parsedForms as $formName => $arr ) {
        $ret [$formName] = array ();
        foreach ( $arr as $ele ) {
            $ret [$formName] [$ele->getAttribute ( "name" )] = $ele->getAttribute ( "value" );
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank for answer, i got error inPHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in  ': \hhb_curl' in line 5

Comment: @CSMMedia that's because you're trying to run it in PHP 5.x - this code was written for PHP7

Comment: how can i run for PHP7 just for specific file php ?

Comment: @CSMMedia google it - 1 way to do it is to set a different fpm handler for *.php files and *.php7 files, and have php5.6-fpm and php7.0-fpm running at the same time, works great for me in nginx+php-fpm - .php files execute as php5 and .php7 files execute as php7